can i reference a class attribute inside the f-string of another attribute
new and playing around to learn.
i want to use one attribute as a complement and automation of another attribute
class ShopItem:
    def __init__(self, name='<unnamed>', price=000.00, utility=0, description="<undefined>"):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.utility = utility
        self.description = description


apple = ShopItem("Apple",
                 1.2,
                 2,
                 f"A delicious apple.\nRestores {self.utility} hp")

The Last Line
wanted the self.description to have utility inside
print(apple.description)
to print:
"Restores 2 hp"
i've tried:
...{utility}...
...{self.utility}...
...{apple.utility}...
...{ShopItem.utility}...
the IDE says
    ... line 12, in <module>
    f"A delicious apple.\nRestores {self.utility}")
                                    ^^^^
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

the not defined changes to whatever is before the dot

No; the string is constructed before ShopItem is called.

You can't with an f-string because the value needs to be provided as the string is constructed. You can instead template your string and use .format to substitute the values named in {<property name>}.
Now there are a few approaches you can take. First is passing self and accessing the value.
class ShopItem:
    def __init__(self, name='<unnamed>', price=000.00, utility=0, description="<undefined>"):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.utility = utility
        self.description = description.format(self=self)

apple = ShopItem("Apple",
                 1.2,
                 2,
                 "A delicious apple.\nRestores {self.utility} hp")

print(apple.description)

Another option you can use is vars(self) to get all the property values of the instance and ** to pass them as keywords to format.
self.description = description.format(**vars(self))

apple = ShopItem("Apple",
                 1.2,
                 2,
                 "A delicious apple.\nRestores {utility} hp")

Alternatively you can be more selective with what you pass as vars gets everything and instead specify only the properties you'd use even if not all of them do get set in the template
apple = ShopItem("Apple",
                 1.2,
                 2,
                 "A delicious apple.\nRestores {utility} hp")

self.description = description.format(price=price, utility=utility)

Keep in mind doing this in the __init__ will mean the formatted description will not change even if the values change

self isn't known at the point of use, but since you know the value of utility set it as a variable and use that:
class ShopItem:

    def __init__(self, name='<unnamed>', price=000.00, utility=0, description='<undefined>'):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.utility = utility
        self.description = description

utility = 2
apple = ShopItem('Apple',
                 1.2,
                 utility,
                 f'A delicious apple.\nRestores {utility} hp')

print(apple.description)

Output:
A delicious apple.
Restores 2 hp


If it is not mandatory to solve the problem with fstring, you can use format
class ShopItem:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name='<unnamed>',
        price=000.00,
        utility=0,
        description="<undefined>"
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.utility = utility
        self.description = description.format(self.utility)


apple = ShopItem(
    name="Apple",
    price=1.2,
    utility=2,
    description="A delicious apple.\nRestores {} hp"
)

print(apple.description)

Basically you are using a placeholder and will change it dinamically within the __init__ with the help of format().
The code you provided is not working because self is not existing at that point, and not even the utility is set that could be used during the assignment of description
self is the instance of the object that is created after the execution of __init__. You are just about to create the instance, with the call of ShopItem(name="Apple", price=1.2, utility=2, description="A delicious apple.\nRestores {} hp")

Too  specific.  What if the description used the price, or the name?
